# Noritz Tankless Water Heater Error Code 90

Tags: water-heater, tankless

My noritz tankless sometimes shuts itself off with error code 90 - a combustion problem. I’ve had a plumber come out and service it since the previous owners didn’t for ten years. I still get the problem intermittently.

I think I’ve found the combination of things that causes it:

- running the shower on hot
- Flushing the adjacent toilet

For some reason this seems to be tripping up the heater and it stops with error code 90.

Pressure problem?

Comment: In general, how is your water pressure? The only way I can think of that flushing a toilet should have any effect on a water heater is if you have low water pressure so the increased flow of cold water decreases the flow of water through the heater. Though arguably that should cause an "overheat" indication, not a combustion problem. If you run a couple of faucets on *cold* at the same time and then flush the toilet, does flow in the faucets noticeably decrease?

Comment: What exact model number? What does the manual say?

Comment: Thank you both. The manual says for error 90 it is a combustion issue and to call a licensed specialist. I did that but might need to find a different specialist. 

Overall water pressure is good but I will test some of the things you mention.